# Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have found a strange problem. when i trying to return data i found an unexpected error.`System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.`i will give provide error details below but before that i want to post code for better understand what actually happend. basically i want to return data to my client side and that time i found error. here is the code:-

```
 public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
      ...
       [JsonIgnore]
       public List<QuestionPost> Qpost { get; set; }
       [JsonIgnore]
       public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

 public class QuestionPost
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int? UserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser User { get; set; }
        public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

 public class Comment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int? UserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser User { get; set; }
        public int? PostId { get; set; }
        public QuestionPost Qpost { get; set; }
    }
```

Datacontext.cs

```
...

 builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Qpost)
            .WithOne(p => p.User)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Comments)
            .WithOne(c => c.User)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.Entity<QuestionPost>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Comments)
            .WithOne(c => c.Qpost)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.PostId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Controller. below, when `questionPosts`  is return and that time I found an error.

```
        [HttpGet]
      public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<QuestionPost>>> GetAllPosts()
      {
         
        var questionPosts = await _context.QuestionPosts
                        .Include(qp => qp.Comments)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.User)
                        .ToListAsync();
        return questionPosts;
       
      }
```

and here is my exception middleware class:-

```
  public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> logger, 
            IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
            _logger = logger;
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
               
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                var response = _env.IsDevelopment()
                    ? new ApiException(context.Response.StatusCode, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace?.ToString())
                    : new ApiException(context.Response.StatusCode, "Internal Server Error");

                var options = new JsonSerializerOptions{PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase};

                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response, options);

                await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
            }
```

I actually wanted return get all `QuestionPost` from controller.and strange things is when `comment` table is empty then i showed my `QuestionPost`'s all data in client side successfully using angular. but after adding some data into `comment` table then actually i found this annoying issue. feel like why only `comment` table creating this issue. I don't understand what's wrong here. here is the error output in my debug console:-

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HMO3JL7E1KV2", Request id "0HMO3JL7E1KV2:0000001B": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpHeaders.ThrowHeadersReadOnlyException()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseHeaders.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.set_ContentType(StringValues value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_ContentType(String value)
         at API.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\Pritom\Desktop\Topper\API\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 34
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Error: Connection id "0HMO3JL7E1KV2", Request id "0HMO3JL7E1KV2:0000001B": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Error: Connection id "0HMO3JL7E1KV2", Request id "0HMO3JL7E1KV2:0000001B": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpHeaders.ThrowHeadersReadOnlyException()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseHeaders.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.set_ContentType(StringValues value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_ContentType(String value)
   at API.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\Pritom\Desktop\Topper\API\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 34
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application
```

**UPDATE**

program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public  static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try 
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
                var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<AppRole>>();
                await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
                await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("DELETE FROM [Connections]");
                await Seed.SeedUsers(userManager, roleManager);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during migration");
            }

            await host.RunAsync();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

startup.cs

```
  public class Startup
    {
     
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddApplicationServices(_config);
             services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPIv5", Version = "v1" });
            });

         services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
               options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());
            });
            
           
            //services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddIdentityServices(_config);
            //services.AddSingleton<InferenceSession>(new InferenceSession("model/stroke.onnx"));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // if (env.IsDevelopment())
            // {
            //     app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //     app.UseSwagger();
            //     app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPIv5 v1"));
            // }
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<PresenceHub>("hubs/presence");
                endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("hubs/message");
            });
            
           
        }
    }
```

I don't understand what's problem there. how to resolve this issue. I am an absolute beginner please help.

Comment: How did you register the middleware? (Can you paste the surrounding code as well?)

Comment: @BenWong My MiddlwWare name is ```ExceptionMiddleware``` and register this by adding startup.cs file ```app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
```

Comment: @BenWong I debugged code when break point is this line ```return questionPosts;``` after that breakpoint will go to ```ExceptionMiddleware.cs``` class all time.

Comment: I don't suppose you can add your Program.cs up above?

Comment: @BenWong yeah. I updated. please check.

Comment: Oh sry, I made a bad assumption that were you on 6; can you add Startup.cs?

Comment: @BenWong updated. please check.

Comment: @BenWong I am in .net 6 by the way. I made same enviroment like .net 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251530/discussion-between-ben-wong-and-peter-parker).

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled? If so then the issue will potentially be due to the serializer "touching" entity references triggering an error while the response is in the process of being composed, then when a service exception handler is raised it is failing and trying to change the response header. As a general rule I don't recommend ever sending entities over transport. Project the entity graph to ViewModels/DTOs to avoid possible serialization issues, plus reduce the overall payload size.

Comment: @StevePy Exactly. I have lazy loading enabled. what i exactly should do please clarify.

Comment: @StevePy also give me an example if possible.

Comment: The work-around is to add `.AsNoTracking()` to your query. This will prevent the lasy loading proxies from being added. This is not a proper fix though as passinng untracked entities is excessive and error prone, particularly when sending data back to the server.  The better solution is to create a ViewModel or DTO class structure for the data your consuming view needs for the data in question, then use `Select()` to populate that view model structure. (eliminating the need for eager loading with `Include`, and avoiding lazy load issues) There are many examples, search for EF Projection.

Comment: I added ```AsNoTracking()``` something like this: ```var questionPosts = await _context.QuestionPosts
                        .Include(qp => qp.Comments)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.User).AsNoTracking()
                        .ToListAsync();
        return questionPosts;``` but still error. it would be very helpful if you will give me an example about ```Select()``` related according to my code.